# unwanted terminal http request output in Python module Azure Identity 1.7.1

Tags: python-3.x, azure

I used to fetch azure client details using a python code from VS code. The output piled up with HTTP status. So I cannot able to identify the original output from the log listing status code in a loop. So how we can avoid these HTTP statuses to the terminal. [image](The code is running in a normal terminal. Not in a debug mode)

Comment: Provide your python code to check from where this is getting displayed in the terminal. Usually this will be displayed when you print the whole request. So if you want to get the specific parameter from the whole request then you may do as "name = req.params.get('name')"

Answer (score 0):

As you need a specific value from output, you can follow the below steps in your python code to get the content from the output response.
Import requests module and get the specific URL response to a response object, after that you can pull the content by just "requests.text".

Below are few samples on how to achieve it:

```
import requests
r =requests.get('URL')
r.status_code # get the status code
r.headers 
r.headers['Content-Type']
r.text #get the content
```